React Native Project The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error
CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePickerManager.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/ios/RNDateTimePickerManager.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNDateTimePicker' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -ivfsstatcache /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphoneos17.4-21E210-99a79c02cfa501706f5b564e46d84afe.sdkstatcache -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fno-color-diagnostics -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability @/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/e6072d4f65d7061329687fe24e3d63a7-common-args.resp -include /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/RNDateTimePicker/RNDateTimePicker-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePickerManager.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePickerManager.dia -c /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/ios/RNDateTimePickerManager.m -o /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePickerManager.o
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/ios/RNDateTimePickerManager.m:47:1: warning: category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class [-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation]
RCT_ENUM_CONVERTER(UIUserInterfaceStyle, (@{
^
In module 'React' imported from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/ios/RNDateTimePickerManager.h:8:
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTConvert.h:229:3: note: expanded from macro 'RCT_ENUM_CONVERTER'
+(type)type : (id)json RCT_DYNAMIC                                                        
^
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTConvert.h:74:1: note: method 'UIUserInterfaceStyle:' declared here

(UIUserInterfaceStyle)UIUserInterfaceStyle:(id)json API_AVAILABLE(ios(12));
^

CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/ios/RNDateTimePicker.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNDateTimePicker' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -ivfsstatcache /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphoneos17.4-21E210-99a79c02cfa501706f5b564e46d84afe.sdkstatcache -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fno-color-diagnostics -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability @/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/e6072d4f65d7061329687fe24e3d63a7-common-args.resp -include /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/RNDateTimePicker/RNDateTimePicker-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker.dia -c /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/ios/RNDateTimePicker.m -o /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker.o
CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker-dummy.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/RNDateTimePicker/RNDateTimePicker-dummy.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNDateTimePicker' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -ivfsstatcache /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphoneos17.4-21E210-99a79c02cfa501706f5b564e46d84afe.sdkstatcache -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fno-color-diagnostics -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability @/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/e6072d4f65d7061329687fe24e3d63a7-common-args.resp -include /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/RNDateTimePicker/RNDateTimePicker-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker-dummy.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker-dummy.dia -c /Users/expo/workingdir/build/PhoenixAppsESM/DMS/RN/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/RNDateTimePicker/RNDateTimePicker-dummy.m -o /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhoenixESM-ckcveveqeqykkkfewxrudqqluzhw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PhoenixESM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNDateTimePicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNDateTimePicker-dummy.o
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')
note: Run script build phase '[Expo] Configure project' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'PhoenixESM' from project 'PhoenixESM')
note: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'PhoenixESM' from project 'PhoenixESM')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

This looks like it might be several questions rather than just one. What are the symptoms that lead you to be believe that you are "missing something"? Is there error log output? What are the symptoms in your app.json that make something look "off". Do you have error output for the "issues in the build process"? Could you please edit the question to focus more clearly on one problem, and include the code and error output?
